GitHub release auto-changes to Draft due to CI
My github project runs GH action on release to publish my Rust crate.
When I create a new release and "publish" it, the release stays published for a few seconds, and later automatically changes to draft.  The CI passes fine, and publishes everything correctly, but the release stays as draft.  Clicking publish on it again re-triggers the same action, which results in a failure (because the same version cannot be pushed to crates.io twice).  Is there a proper way to run publishing script whenever release is created?
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]
  release:
    types: [ published ]
  workflow_dispatch:


It looks like you configured your CI to publish draft releases here and here.
These end up running after you publish a release. Until GitHub deletes historical logs, evidence of that is here.
Then actions-gh-release finds your manually created release here and changes it to a draft here.
You wouldn't have to re-release if you corrected your workflow file to avoid marking the original release as a draft.

oh, silly me - so what should be the publishing process? Should I create a tag instead of a release?  Or is the process ok, just need to not mark it as draft?

There are multiple options but I'm guessing you can manually create a published GitHub release (which may involve manually creating a tag) and make the CI publish the crate but not mark the GitHub release as draft. There is probably also a way to only manually create tags and have the CI do the rest.
